# Screen in Android Virtual Device is too large

Tags: java, android, xml

I've this problem that my screen in Android Virtual Device is out of view. I have tried reducing the scaling by -0.75, as stated by others, but it doesn't seem to help.

[image: Screen Shot of my AVD]

Notice how the button to unlock the screen is out of view. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like your physical screen resolution is too low. Or try enlarging the emulator window?

Comment: If that does not work, select a device with a smaller resolution. E.g. xhdpi to hdpi, or something like that.

Comment: @user7777777 hey thank you! it seems fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the context menu of windows. Right-click with your mouse on the AVD and chose *move*. Then your AVD should not be "locked" anymore (and maybe you can adjust the size then too).